# Can we test JMS messages to ActiveMQ using SOAPUI?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, soapui

I read some documentation on SOAPUI.

It explains that we can send JMS messages to ActiveMQ.

I tried to implement similarly.

But I am facing issues.

I completed configuration as mentioned in this link

https://www.soapui.org/documentation/jms/config.html

In the next link https://www.soapui.org/jms/working-with-jms-messages.html it explains about working with JMS messages.

In this link they have asked to add JMS endpoint.
But I am not able to find option for that.

I wonder if this option is available in free version.
Or it is part of pro version?

Could you help me achieve this?

Also provide me any other links where this that will explain how I can send JMS messages to ActiveMQ using SOAPUI.

I already googled it but unfortunately very limited info is available.

Comment: Are you using jms for sending `soap` message? or it is just plain text message? If so, then you need to just use the `groovy script` test step to achieve the same, and you have already have the right link (2nd one).

Comment: Hey Rao thanks a lot for your reply.
I could send JMS message to ActiveMQ using SOAPUI. 
I am using Groovy script for sending messages to ActiveMQ.
Now I want to use IBM MQ instead of ActivMQ. 
1) Could you please let me know what are the changes with respect to configuration that I need to make for IBM MQ?
2) The working script for ActiveMQ will work with IBM MQ as well? Or i need to modify Groovy Script?
3) Could you please provide me link for sending JMS message to IBMMQ using SOAPUI?

Comment: Could you please specify if you need to send SOAP message over jms?

Comment: It is plain text message

Comment: Looks you already accepted the answer. If this is a new question, then I would request you to open a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy. Create a SOAP project using the WSDL file [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlgNJ.jpg). Then right click on WSDL endpoint bindings. And add JMS end point. Give your configuration and other options such as session, send, receive. I have attached a sample image to assist you doing this. Hope this helps. Happy coding.

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlgNJ.jpg) http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl

Comment: Hi Ravindra, Thanks for your information.
This info is valid for SOAP based project. Where as I do not have SOAP based project. So I do not have wsdl url.
Mine is JMS project. Not sure how this can be done for JMS project?

Comment: Hi Ravindra, I could able to add JMS endpoint. Now I want to send messages to JMS Queue using this endpoint. Could you please provide any url on internet with respect to that?

Comment: Just create a SOAP project, give the JMS end point, put the request payload and click on send. It should send the message to the JMS end point. Use the ActiveMQ web console to verify the message.

Comment: I am glad that you made it ! :)

Comment: Hey Ravindra thanks again.
I could send message to ActiveMQ using SOAPUI.

Comment: Hey Ravindra thanks again.
I could send message to ActiveMQ using SOAPUI.
Could you tell me what are the chages that I need to use IBM MQ instead of ActiveMQ?
Could you please provide me any links for sending JMS messages to IBM MQ using SOAPUI?

Comment: Hey I am sorry, I have no much experience in IBM MQ.